# excel vba i have to find a specific set of letters amongst many in one cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, find, vba

I want to do.

```
    If Cells(1,1).Value = "XYZ" then 
    'something'
```

But there can be other letters in the cell. like a cell [ZZZ XYZ YYY WWW]. 
How do i get around that XYZ can be anywhere in that cell. 
only find that specific order of the letters. 
And if its not in that specific cell the if command should not trigger.

hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
If InStr(Cells(1, 1), "XYZ") > 0 Then
```

Answer (score 1):

```
If Cells(1,1).value like "*XYZ*" Then
    ...
End If
```

the `*` denotes any number of characters. You can also do single character with `?`.
example

```
"AXYZB" like "*XYZ*" 'is true
"AXYZB" like "?XYZ?" 'is true
"AZXYZBA" like "?XYZ?" 'is false
```

you can also do in between

```
"XYZ" like "X?Z"   'is true
"XYYYZ" like "X*Z" 'is true
```